# QR code to trigger action on installed native app in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, qr-code

How can I trigger action on a windows phone app? Let say I want to navigate to a certain page in my native app by scanning the QR code, how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3):

First of all this is an idea, what i would do is to create a [custom uri scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_LaunchingaURIusingProximity), so when the QR code has been read, the device will navigate to the page you pointed, it doesn't matter if your application is running

- in `WMAppManifest` right after `Tokens` add

> ```
>   <Extensions>
>   <Protocol Name="yourprotocol" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
>   </Extensions>
> ```

- than in `App.cs` add `RootFrame.UriMapper = new CustomUriMapper();`
- in your case `CustomUriMapper` should look like this

> ```
> class CustomUriMapper : UriMapperBase
> {
>     private string tempUri;
>     public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
>     {
>         tempUri = System.Net.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.ToString());          
>         if (tempUri.Contains("yourprotocol"))
>         { 
>          return new Uri("YourPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
>         }
>         else
>             {
>                 return new Uri("MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
>             }           
>     }
> }
> ```

Let me know how it goes (:

Comment: [An MSDN source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx/css) for your directions.

Comment: I've done all this, but scanning [QR codes generated by kaywa](http://qrcode.kaywa.com/) just produces a "message" for the user to read that is the URL. It doesn't actually launch the app. Is this a shortcoming of WP8 itself, or the method of creating the QR code?

Comment: It looks like WP8 will treat any non http(s): scheme as a text message when scanned. But you can work around this by using any HTTP redirector (e.g. a URL shortener) to create an HTTP url that will redirect to the customscheme: URL, which then activates your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn uriassociationname:?parameters for example, to a shortened url with tinyurl and the phone will run that and start the corresponding app.